# Java DatagramChannel - Read All Available Datagrams in a Single "Reading" Call

Tags: java, nio, multicast, datagram

I am trying to figure out how to get all available datagram in a single reading call (which would hopefully translate into a single system call), similar to calling [rcvmmsg](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recvmmsg.2.html) in C++.

Right now my code looks like so:

```java
    private final Selector_;
    private final ByteBuffer buffer_ = ByteBuffer.allocate(2048);

    public UDPClient() {
        try {
            selector_ = Selector.open();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
    public void joinGroup(String group_ip, int group_port, String iface_name)  throws IOException {
        final NetworkInterface iface = NetworkInterface.getByName(iface_name);
        final DatagramChannel channel = DatagramChannel.open(StandardProtocolFamily.INET)
                .setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_REUSEADDR, true)
                .bind(new InetSocketAddress(group_port))
                .setOption(StandardSocketOptions.IP_MULTICAST_IF, iface);
        channel.configureBlocking(false);
        channel.join(InetAddress.getByName(group_ip), iface);
        channel.register(selector_, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
    }

    public void recvDatagrams() throws IOException {
        if (selector_.selectNow() > 0) {
            for (SelectionKey key: selector_.selectedKeys()) {
                final DatagramChannel channel = (DatagramChannel)key.channel();
                channel.receive(buffer_);
                buffer_.flip();
                // Handle buffer ...
                buffer_.clear();
            }
            selector_.selectedKeys().clear();
        }
    }
```

My desired reception code would be something like this:

```java
   ByteBuffer[] buffers_ = new ByteBuffer[64];
   // [...]
   channel.read(buffers_);
   // Handle datagrams
```

This would allow me to receive up to 64 datagrams in one call if they were already queued up on my network interface. The problem I am facing is that read() if for "connected" channels. My channels are not connected, I don't know the source, I am merely joining a multicast group and receiving datagrams from it.

Please note that I am aware I can do a `while` loop on the `channel.receive()` call to populate the `buffers_` array myself, but this is not the point of my post.

Cheers!

Comment: DatagramChannel supports scattering reads when connected. It does not support scattering receive.

Comment: I appreciate the help on this Alan, that is unfortunately what I suspected.